# JQuery check if at least one input is filled (not empty & not zero)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can't figure out how to check if at least one input is filled which means it is not empty and the value is greater than zero.

I can check it for **empty** value or **zero** but I want to check for both values.

Tried to put **&&** after `value!=""` which didn't work.

```
$('#id_calculator_form').find(':input[value!=""]').not('#id_postcode'){

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter based on multiple values

```
var els = $('#id_calculator_form :input').filter('[value!=""], [value!="0"]');

if (els.length > 0) {...
```

Note that selecting by `value` attribute, only works on elements with a set value attribute, if you want to filter based on inputted value, you should check the property instead

```
var els = $('#id_calculator_form :input').filter(function() {
    return this.value !== "" && this.value !== "0";
});

if (els.length > 0) {... // at least one input is not zero or empty
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work for some reason. console.log($('#id_calculator_form :input').filter('[value!=""], [value!="0"]')) returns all inputs, even those which are increased to 2.

Comment: Try the second approach if you're checking this in an event handler ?

Comment: Thanks, yes it's on change any input handler. The second approach works.